# How to split Views exposed filters into separate blocks

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I would like more flexibility of my exposed filters so styling and organization can be better.

I will be using 3-5 exposed filters and rather that oranizing them by CSS only i thought it would be nice to have each one in separate blocks.

My reason for this is to display filtering options the way most are use to, Ascednig/descending and small to large(or cheap to expensive) up top fairly small

and on the left side a detailed selection of sub category options (size, brand etc...)

If there is a better solution im all ears.

Im using:
- Drupal 7
- Views 7.x-3.8
- better exposed filters

Answer (score 2):

The [MEFIBS - More exposed forms in blocks](https://drupal.org/project/mefibs) module provides this functionality.

Comment: Be careful with this one as it does not work with panels.